# Is there a way to change NameId in SAML custom policies?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to change to NameID for the user email in custom policies, but can't figure out how. We started with the [SAML tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers) on Microsoft.

Email in `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`:

```
<ClaimType Id="email">
    <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="email" />
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/email" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <UserHelpText>Email address that can be used to contact you.</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
    <Restriction>
      <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&amp;'^_`{}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" HelpText="Please enter a valid email address." />
    </Restriction>
  </ClaimType>
```

`TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml` (only technical profile):

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_company" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_altitude3Id" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isAvivaBroker" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_avivaAvantageId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isApproved" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_phoneExtension" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobile" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="streetAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="city" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="state" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="postalcode" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Part of `SignUpOrSigninSAML.xml`:

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue=""/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId"/>
  </OutputClaims>
  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="objectId" ExcludeAsClaim="true"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

In the metadata, I have that (`SignUpOrSigninSAML.xm`l):

```
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you update your `RelyingParty` definition to the following that should output the `email` in the `NameId` with a format of `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress`:

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue=""/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId"/>
  </OutputClaims>
  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" ExcludeAsClaim="true"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I've left the `email` in as an additional attribute to be included in your assertion, but if you're only interested in it being in the `NameId` then you could remove the `<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue=""/>` line.

Comment: Works like a charm! Very good solution. Do I still need to specify to protocol in my ```TrustFrameworkBase.xml``` under Email for Saml2 or I can remove it? and what about the ```<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />``` in ```TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml```?

Comment: @AntoineBrisebois-Roy the `Protocol` in `TrustFrameworkBase` will apply to the attribute in the assertion but not the `NameId` so you can remove it if you don't also want to include the email as an attribute. 

The line in `TrustFrameworkExtensions` you need to keep if you're reading the email back from the user's profile in AAD. That line is mapping the email address from the sign in names collection in AAD to your email claim in the B2C policy journey, which is then mapped to your `NameId` when the token is written.

Comment: I have made a commit to add the `format` param to our docs only yesterday, should be live soon.